# How do I get and filter a list of files from TIdFTP?

Tags: delphi, ftp, indy10

I am trying to make a utility to scan our FTP site for old files.

I have come across Indy FTP as part of RAD Studio today and like how it works, but how do I do the following?

1. Get a list of files/directories that I can see (go from TIdFTP.List() to listbox).
2. Narrow those results by a date (showing filename/path)

Comment: Welcome, Please show what you have tried so we can assist.

Comment: take a look at : http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/demos/index.en.aspx

Comment: I'm confused how you can say you "like how it works" when the level of your question seems to suggest you've not actually observed it working at all. If you had, I would assume you'd have seen it get a list of files, since that functionality is surely included in every single demo ever written.

Comment: as i said, im new to the whole indyFTP object, and didnt realise there were demos. the answer below has told me what i need :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TIdFTP` has a `DirectoryListing` collection that you can loop through after calling `TIdFTP.List()`.  Each item in the collection has `FileName`, `ItemType`, and `ModifiedDate` properties, amongst many others.

There are many FTP listing formats used online, and Indy implements many parsers for them, however most of the parsers are not enabled by default.  If the FTP server(s) you are connecting to do not support the `MLSD` command (that parser is always enabled), and/or you are setting the `TIdFTP.UseMLIS` property to false, then you will need to either:

1. add individual `IdFTPListParse...` units to your `uses` clause to enable just the parsers for the particular formats that you want to support.
2. add the `IdAllFTPListParsers` unit to your `uses` clause to enable all of the parsers.